# Angular: Filter Multiple Items

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, angularjs, filtering

i'm new to angular and i'm having issues with the filtering function.

first of all, the content is getting pulled in from a json file. pretty simple:

```
[
 {
    "id":"0",
    "animal":"cat",
    "breed":"siamese",
    "name":"kevin",
    "photo": "/images/kevin.jpg"
 },
 {
    "id":"1",
    "animal":"dog",
    "breed":"pug",
    "name":"barney",
    "photo": "/images/barney.jpg"
 }
]
```

and so forth.

html on the page. the nav points come from their own json files that have nothing to do with the data, just meant to create the menus and pass the value:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in animal_data">
    <a href="" ng-click="filterData(item.animal)">{{item.animal | uppercase}}</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in breed_data">
    <a href="" ng-click="filterData(item.breed)">{{item.breed | uppercase}}</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

script for the filter:

```
$scope.filterData = function(item)
   {           
       var passFilterType = $filter('filterType')($scope.original_data, item); 

       if(passFilterType.length > 0)  
       {
           $scope.isLoading = true;
           $scope.isSuccessful = false;
           $scope.percentLoaded = 0;   

            $scope.thumbnails = passFilterType;

           loadImages();

       }else{
            console.log("error");
       }
 }


   function loadImages()
    {
       var passImages = getImages();

       if(passImages.length > 0)
       {   
           preloader.preloadImages(passImages).then(handleResolve, handleReject, handleNotify);
       }
    }
```

my plan is to convert the LI's to check boxes and then that brings me to the point where i need help. is there a way to take what i've already set up to use it for filtering multiple animals and breeds?

thanks to anyone who can help.

Answer (score 1):

I think this might be what you're looking for (run the code snippet at the end), or give you an idea or two. You might want to reorganize the code some for your purposes.

the key points are:

- ng-reapeat checkboxes based off unique breeds and animals. I used the unique filter from ui.filters, but you could roll your own.

  `<label ng-repeat="item in animal_data | unique:'breed'">{{item.breed}}
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="selected[item.breed]"></input>
  </label>`
- using the built in filter on the ng-repeat that lists results, and providing a function for its expression that evaluates to true for selected items from checkboxes.

  `<li ng-repeat="item in animal_data | filter:check(selected)">`
- And creating that function:

  `$scope.check = function(selected) {
    return function(item) {

      if (selected[item.animal] || selected[item.breed])
        return true;
      else
        return false;
      };
   }`

And all together...

```js
var app = angular.module('testApp', ['ui.directives', 'ui.filters']);

app.controller('testCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.selected = {};

  $scope.animal_data = [{
    "id": "0",
    "animal": "cat",
    "breed": "siamese",
    "name": "kevin",
    "photo": "/images/kevin.jpg"
  }, {
    "id": "1",
    "animal": "dog",
    "breed": "pug",
    "name": "barney",
    "photo": "/images/barney.jpg"
  }, {
    "id": "2",
    "animal": "dog",
    "breed": "poodle",
    "name": "charlie",
    "photo": "/images/barney.jpg"
  }];


  $scope.check = function(selected) {
    return function(item) {
      if (selected[item.animal] || selected[item.breed])
        return true;
      else
        return false;
    };
  }

  $scope.filterData = function(item) {
    var passFilterType = $filter('filterType')($scope.original_data, item);



    if (passFilterType.length > 0) {
      $scope.isLoading = true;
      $scope.isSuccessful = false;
      $scope.percentLoaded = 0;

      $scope.thumbnails = passFilterType;

      loadImages();

    } else {
      console.log("error");
    }
  }
});


function loadImages() {
  var passImages = getImages();

  if (passImages.length > 0) {
    preloader.preloadImages(passImages).then(handleResolve, handleReject, handleNotify);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui/0.4.0/angular-ui.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app='testApp'>
  <div ng-controller="testCtrl">

    <li ng-repeat="item in animal_data">{{item}}</li>
    <ul>
      BREED:
      <label ng-repeat="item in animal_data | unique:'breed'">{{item.breed}}
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="selected[item.breed]"></input>
      </label>
      <br/>ANIMAL:
      <label ng-repeat="item in animal_data | unique:'animal'">{{item.animal}}
        <input ng-model="selected[item.animal]" type="checkbox"></input>
      </label>
      

      <table width="400">
        <thead>
          <th>animal</th>
          <th>breed</th>
          <th>name</th>
          <th>link</th>
          <tr ng-repeat="item in animal_data | filter:check(selected)">
            <td>{{item.animal | uppercase}}</td>
            <td>{{item.breed}}</td>
            <td>{{item.name}}</td>
            <td> <a href="" ng-click="filterData(item)">filterDataLink</a>
            </td>
          </tr>
      </table>

  </div>
</div>
```